# How to access array of structure in another file

Tags: c++, structure

How to access array of structure in another file.lets say i have 3 file  1.h 2.cpp 3.cpp as below

1.h

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    struct st
  {
       Int i;
        char ch[10];

    };
   struct st var[10];
```

2.cpp

```
   #include"1.h"
     int main
     {
        int s;
       //here i hve scannd value of i frm user
       callotherfile();
      }
```

i
3.cpp

```
    #include"1.h
     int p;
       void callotherfile(void)
      { 
        for(p=1;p<=10;p++)
       cout<<var.i[p]<<end;// is it good can i excess?
      }
```

here i am getting errir as  p and s are non of class type please help me to fix it

i am compiling as g++ 2.cpp 3.cpp

Comment: There are a lot of errors:
- minor, like capital I in Int in 1.h;
- 2.cpp has no idea bout callotherfile function;
- 1.h: you can't define var[10] in a header file and include this file in multiple cpp files. You've got two compilation units - 2.cpp and 3.cpp and both of them got definition of var[10], which one linker should use? You should declare var[10] as extern in the header file and define it in one of cpp files. etc,...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest the following changes:

1. Changes to `1.hpp`.

   1. Remove `#include <stdio.h>`. you don't need it.
   2. Provide a declaration for the array, not a definition.

      ```
       struct st
       {
          int i; // You had Int, not int. I assume that was a typo.
          char ch[10];
       };
       extern struct st var[10];
      ```
2. Changes to `2.cpp`. Provide a declaration for `callotherfile` before you use it.

   ```
   #include "1.h"
   void callotherfile(void);
   int main()
   {
      int s;  // This is an unused variable. It can be removed.
      callotherfile(); // You had a : not a ;. I assume that was a typo
   }
   ```
3. Changes to `3.cpp`.

   1. Add `#include <iostream>`. You need it to use `std::cout` and `std::endl`.
   2. Provide a definition of the array.
   3. Use `cout` and `endl` with the `std::` scope.
   4. Since `var` is an array, use `var[p].i` instead of `var.i`.
   5. Stop the loop when the loop counter reaches `p`, not when it exceeds `p`. Please note that `10` is not a valid index for an array with `10` elements.

      ```
      #include <iostream>

      #include "1.h"
      struct st var[10];
      int p;  // This variable can be moved to the function scope.
      void callotherfile(void)
      { 
         for(p=1;p<10;p++) // You had p<=10
            std::cout<<var[p].i<<std::endl;
      }
      ```

Answer (score 0):

Changes you need to do

> 1 #include "1.h" in `3.cpp` this might be a typo but this will also not solve ur problem just to note
>
> 2 You need to include `3.cpp` in the file '2.cpp'
>
> 3 compile it using this command 'g++ 2.cpp'
>
> 4 callotherfile(): put semicolon ; here

5 `cout<<var.i<<end` put semicolon ; at the end